# Get All Pages as strings in array

Tags: pages, wp-list-pages

I try somehow to get array of pages names. I don't think it's possible in some default method from WP.

```
<?php $args = array(
  'authors'      => '',
  'child_of'     => 0,
  'date_format'  => get_option('date_format'),
  'depth'        => 0,
  'echo'         => 0,
  'exclude'      => '',
  'include'      => '',
  'link_after'   => '',
  'link_before'  => '',
  'post_type'    => 'page',
  'post_status'  => 'publish',
  'show_date'    => '',
  'sort_column'  => 'menu_order, post_title',
  'sort_order'   => '',
  'title_li'     => __('Pages'), 
  'walker'       => new Walker_Page
)
;?>

$arr = wp_list_pages($args);

print_r($arr);
```

But this return LINK-s "< A >" tags ... Maybe in PHP I can in some way "transfrom" this links to string ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`get_pages()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) to fetch an array of page objects, then pass that result to [`wp_list_pluck()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck) to extract an array of just page titles:

```
$page_titles = wp_list_pluck( get_pages(), 'post_title' );
print_r( $page_titles );
```

Comment: FYI This was auto-flagged as low quality for content length.

Comment: Very nice, Milo.  Did not know `wp_list_pluck()` existed.  Two lines - done!

Answer (score 0):

As with most tasks in web development, there is more than one way to achieve this.  My suggestion is to use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) amd fetch all pages by [post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters).

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

//Loop here....
```

**EDIT:** after re-reading your question, I see that I failed to note the "array" requirement.  This approach creates a new instance of the WP_Query class and returns an object, not an array.  With that in mind, corrected version follows:

```
<?php
$page_titles = array();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

// If there are pages, let's loop
if($the_query->have_posts()):  
    while($the_query->have_posts()):
        $the_query->the_post(); 
        $page_titles[] = get_the_title();  // Add each page title to your array
    endwhile; 

else : 
    // Do stuff if no pages
endif;

// Display array contents
echo '<pre>';
print_r($page_titles);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Please add a bit of explanation. This also keeps mods and higher rep users from looking through your question due to auto-flagging ;)